# Prove that g is a primitive root modulo m.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

We have natural number $m \ge 2$ which is relatively prime with integer number $g$. 
Let's assume that for every prime divider $q|\varphi(m) $ we have
$$ g^{ \frac{\varphi(m)}{q} } \not\equiv 1 (mod \mbox{    } m).$$
Prove that $g$ is a primitive root modulo m.

($\varphi(m)$ is Euler function)

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: The problem has not been stated clearly. Maybe you really want to show that if $g$ is not a primitive root, then there is a prime $q$ such that $g^{\varphi(m)/q}\equiv 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake. I have to prove that g is a primitive root.

Comment: Also,this command is copied from a book, I do not know how to write it differently.

Comment: The edit (removing the not) makes a lot of difference! And instead of "there is" one should have something like "we have" or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a usual way to check weather $g$ is a primitive root.

To prove $g$ is a primitive root, it is equivalent to prove $\varphi(m)$ is the order of $g$ modulo $m$.

Since $\gcd(g,m)=1$, by Euler's theorem, we have $g^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1(\mod m)$.

Now, if $g^{\frac{\varphi(m)}{p}}\neq 1(\mod m)$, then $g^d\neq 1(\mod m)$ for all $d|\varphi(m)$ and $d<\varphi(m)$. Then consider the definition of order, we get $\varphi(m)$ is the order of $g$ modulo $m$.

Comment: So i guess this is it ?

Comment: Yes. And you may figure out the details yourself.

Comment: If we don't get "=1 (mod m)" from any $g^{\frac{\varphi(m)}{p}}$, then we have just $g^{\varphi(m)}$ left to give us "=1 (mod m)" . Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. .

Answer (score 0):

Coming at it from the other direction....

Consider the case where $h$, coprime to $m$, is **not** a primitive root $\bmod m$. Then we have some $k<\varphi(m)$ such that $h^k \equiv 1 \bmod m$. Also, we know from [Euler's totient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) that $h^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \bmod m$, so certainly $ k \mid \varphi(m)$. Thus there is some $a>1$ such that $ ak = \varphi(m)$ and some prime $p$ such that $p \mid a$ ; then there is a $b$ such that $a=pb$ and $pbk = \varphi(m)$.  Then

$$ h^\frac{\varphi(m)}{p} = h^{bk} = (h^k)^b \equiv 1^b \equiv 1 \bmod m
$$

Therefore if we cannot find a reduced exponent of this sort for a given $g$ coprime to $m$, $g$ must be a primitive root.